# Mapping population using tmap orders incorrectly

Tags: r, gis

I'm trying to map population in California counties for 2019. Using `class()` I saw the data is stored as characters so I changed it to numeric to get accurate results for `summary()`. When mapping, the values are being separated in an incorrect order (see legend). Not sure how else to solve this!

```
camap <- readOGR("CA_Counties_Pop2019.shp")
camap <- spTransform(camap, CRS("+init=epsg:4326"))

pop2019 <- as.numeric(as.character(camap$POP_2019))
summary(pop2019)

camap$poprange[pop2019 >= 1000 & pop2019 < 100000] <- "1,000-100,000"
camap$poprange[pop2019 >= 100000 & pop2019  < 500000] <- "100,000-500,000"
camap$poprange[pop2019 >= 500000 & pop2019  < 1000000] <- "500,000 - 1,000,000"
camap$poprange[pop2019 >= 1000000 & pop2019  < 5000000] <- "1,000,000 - 5,000,000"
camap$poprange[pop2019 >= 5000000 & pop2019  < 11000000] <- "5,000,000 - 11,000,000"

tm_shape(camap) + tm_fill("poprange", palette="Reds")`
```

- The map:

[image]

Comment: You need to define the "pop range" column as a factor in the desire order.  There are many questions here demonstrating the question.

Comment: i've been testing out the factor stuff but i'm fairly new to R and don't understand how it could apply to my scenario? how can i use that to define ranges for each category like 1,000 - 100,000?

Comment: Here is a simple example: `factor(c("Fri", "Wed", "Mon"), levels=c("Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thur", "Fri"))` the first vector is your vector of labels and then the levels option defines the ordering. Then it will plot in order. See this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66722291/choosing-ordering-for-labels-in-geometric-bar-plot

Comment: To complete @Dave2e's comment, and perhaps make more concrete the use of the code he proposed just above, you can refer to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68569749/how-to-change-the-order-of-legend-elements-in-tmap). Hope this helps. Cheers.

Comment: these are helpful, however i seem to be getting errors. so would i just add the factor line in right before plotting? as in, should i keep everything else the same and just add that in?

Comment: Yes change to factors just before plotting.  If you are still having problems then please edit your question and provide an update.

Comment: If you use `base::cut` to divide your categories instead of your series of `[pop2019 >= ... & pop2019 < ...]` this will already give an ordered factor as the output